# Regex to find URLs unless they include a list of strings

Tags: regex

I have this the following expression which is working well for my needs:

```
(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.(com|net|info)\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

It does a pretty good job of finding URLs which are hardcoded in a large codebase. Obviously, it has some false positives for things like `Using System.net`, but some of the valid URLs don't include `http(s)://` unfortunately.

So now I want to be able to exclude certain things, including `system.net` (false positives) and `google.com` (common urls in comments).

How can I do this?

Ideally the list would just include `google` and `system`. Something like `(!google|!system)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received this answer on Reddit less than an hour after posting.

> you can use a negative lookahead for this.
>
> ```
> \b(?!google\.com|system.net)
> ```
>
> \b is there to make sure it starts at a word boundary (like after a
> space or a dot there)

https://regex101.com/r/pwj3Xn/1

Credit to [u/Kompaan86/](https://www.reddit.com/user/Kompaan86/)